# How to feed long sentences to transformer model

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have a PyTorch/Transformers model for NER. When I use it for inference, it crashes with too long sentences (the famous CUDA out of memory).

Is there a way to break sentences in the same fashion as the [spacy span_getters](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-transformers/blob/master/spacy_transformers/span_getters.py)?

Is there a transformers' argument that can be set for that?

Thanks.

Comment: How long is your sentence after encoding? Please post relevant code how you currently transform your input sentences, and how you feed them into the model. See [mcve] and [ask] for more help.

Comment: What is your input? Paragraphs? Documents? Do you want to retrieve English sentences from them?